# Como posso comparar valores nesse algoritmo de calculadora

Tags: algoritmo, visualg

O objetivo deste algoritmo, é ser um pequeno jogo de calcular, onde compara o resultado da operação informada pelo usuário com o valor correto da mesma e assim dizer se o usuário acertou ou não o resultado da operação. Estou testando com a operação de soma, por enquanto.

```
algoritmo "Jogo Calculadora"
// Data : 16/1/2017
// Seção de Declarações
var
num1, num2, opcao, resultado, cont, b: inteiro
inicio
// Seção de Comandos
cont <- 0
escreva ("Digite o 1º número (de 1 a 10): ")
leia (num1)
escreva ("Qual operação deseja? ")
escreval ("[1] - Somar")
escreval ("[2] - Subtrair")
escreval ("[3] - Multiplicar")
escreval ("[4] - Dividir")
escreval ("[5] - Sair")
leia (opcao)
escreval ("Digite agora o 2º número (de 1 a 10): ")
leia (num2)
escreva ("Qual o resultado? ")
leia (resultado)

escolha opcao
caso 1
   se (num1 > 0) entao
      se (num1 <= 10) entao
         enquanto (cont <= 10 ) faca
            b <- num1 + cont
            escreval (b)
            cont <- cont + 1
            se (cont == resultado) entao
               escreval ("Parabéns você acertou!")
            seNao
               escreval ("Você errou!")
            fimEnquanto

         seNao
            escreval ("Valor inválido!")
         fimSe
      seNao
         escreval ("Valor inválido!")
      fimSe
   caso 2
   caso 3
   caso 4
   caso 5
   fimEscolha
fimalgoritmo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
escolha opcao
caso 1
   se (num1 > 0) e (num2>0) entao
      se (num1 <= 10) e (num2 <= 10) entao
         cont <- num1 + num2
         se (cont == resultado) entao
         escreval ("Parabéns você acertou!")
         seNao
         escreval ("Você errou!")
         fimSe
      seNao
       escreval ("Valor inválido!")
      fimSe
    seNao
      escreval ("Valor inválido!")
    fimSe 
fim caso 1
```

Comment: existe algum comando para se encerrar um caso e não executar os seguintes?

Comment: Sim existem varias maneiras e vc ja quase fez isso. Voce primeiro perguntou ao usuario:

leia (opcao)

e depois vc fez:
caso 1 
Voce poderia escrever 
SE CASO 1

Assim SE escolher caso 1 ou 2 ou 3 ou 4 so sera executado aquele caso escolhido e depois fim do programa. 

Voce poderia ussar tambem opcoes mais bruscas como por exemplo PARAR:

fim caso 1
PARAR 

Esse PARAR pararia a execucao do programa.

Comment: muito obrigada... tirou minha dúvida e resolveu o problema.